# How do you translate "Compliments of" into Russian?

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

I am writing something predominately in English but want to add the Russian equivalent of the phrase "compliments of [Name]" instead of writing it in English. This isn't to say that somebody is being complimented but that something is provided through the courtesy of the person being named.

What I found looking online (Google translate mainly), was that it would read:

комплиментом (komplimentom) followed by the name. Is this correct?

Additionally, and perhaps this is meant for a different thread, why does Google Translate use the Russian alphabet and then "komplimentom" underneath? If I'm writing everything else in English, can I use "komplimentom" in italics?

Comment: Never use Google Translate. It's virtually always ridiculous. The Russian generated by it usually requires reverse-translation into English, and not everyone will be familiar with the expression "compliments of" to reconstruct the meaning of the utter baffling randomness that is **комплиментом**.

What is the context, what is it that appears "compliments of" someone, who is it, and why do you want that particular phrase in Russian?

Comment: If the phrase means "thanks to X", something is done, благодаря Николаю.

Comment: Or "Many thanks to X, who helped..."Благодарность (кому), ".

Comment: Also can be: "Отдельное спасибо (Имя [in Dative case]) за ... (eg., любезно предоставленные материалы)".

Comment: It is not possible to translate this without knowing context. Vitaly gave you a number of possible translations but which it is depends on the purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't think of a simple one-to-one translation. Here are a few possible translations:

**Любезно предоставленный**

> - *Фотографии в книге любезно предоставлены компанией IBM.*  Pictures in this book are compliments of IBM Corp.
> - *Цветы для нашего праздника любезно предоставлены городской администрацией.*  Flowers for our celebration are compliments of City Hall.

**Подарок от кого-то**

> - *Билеты в театр - подарок от руководства компании.*  Theater tickets are compliments of corporate management.

**Подарен кем-то**

> - *Экспонаты в этой галерее подарены семьёй Николаевых.* Artifacts in this gallery are compliments of Nikolayev family.

Comment: +1 for "любезно предоставленный"